# C++ pass "this" to an imported lambda function from another file (in order to access member variables)

Tags: c++, oop, lambda, import

I need to pass a lambda function to a library *(which then gets executed in certain conditions)*, therefore I cannot modify the type signature.

But the "passing" of the lambda function happens inside a `class`/`struct` and the function **needs to access other member variables**. This can normally be achieved by capturing "this" in the lambda function declaration (`[this](...){}`).

But the problem is, I would like to declare the lambda function in a **separate file** than the struct is *(due to code clarity and better project structure)*.

##### So how do I pass the "this" to the imported lambda function?

This is basically what I would like to achieve:

```cpp
/* -- handlers.h -- */
auto message = [/* how to capture "this" (worker_t) here? */](WSConnection *ws, std::string_view message)
{
    if (message == "closedown")
    {
        // this "listen_socket_" is a member of the worker_t that this function needs to access
        us_listen_socket_close(0, listen_socket_);
        ws->close();
    }
}

/* -- main.cpp -- */
#include "handlers.h"

struct worker_t
{
    // the lambda function needs to access these members
    struct us_listen_socket_t *listen_socket_;
    std::shared_ptr<uWS::App> app_;

    void work()
    {
        app_ = std::make_shared<uWS::App>();

        app_->ws<PerSocketData>("/*", {
           .message = message, // I would like to just PASS the function here, not declare it
           // ...
        });

        // ...
    }
};
```

Is there a better solution than declaring a "wrapper" lambda function in-place and then calling the imported message function inside it like this?

```cpp
/* -- handlers.h -- */
auto message = [](worker_t* self, WSConnection *ws, std::string_view message)
{
    if (message == "closedown")
    {
        /* Bye bye */
        us_listen_socket_close(0, self->listen_socket_);
        ws->close();
    }
}

/* -- main.cpp -- */
#include "handlers.h"

struct worker_t
{
    // the lambda function needs to access these members
    struct us_listen_socket_t *listen_socket_;
    std::shared_ptr<uWS::App> app_;

    void work()
    {
        app_ = std::make_shared<uWS::App>();

        app_->ws<PerSocketData>("/*", {
           .message = [this](WSConnection *ws, std::string_view message)
           {
               message(this, ws, message);
           }
           // ...
        });

        // ...
    }
};
```

Comment: In your first block of code you have global lambda `message`, so there is only one instance. You cannot capture potential multiple workers into single lambda instance ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could make the lambda declared in "handlers.h" a higher-order function that returns a lambda.

```
auto make_message = [](worker_t* self)
{
    return [self](WSConnection *ws, std::string_view message)
    {
        if (message == "closedown")
        {
            /* Bye bye */
            us_listen_socket_close(0, self->listen_socket_);
            ws->close();
        }
    };
};

void worker_t::work()
{
    app_ = std::make_shared<uWS::App>();

    app_->ws<PerSocketData>("/*", {
       .message = make_message(this),
       // ...
    });

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This should also fix the "global lambda function" problem with multiple worker instances that @R2RT mentioned in the main comment section, right?

Comment: Yes, it should. Each time the higher-order function is called, a new lambda is created.